# SQL LIKE '%/_Description' returns unexpected results

Tags: sql, wildcard, sql-like

I use the `LIKE` statement like `'%/_Description'` but got the following results:

1. Description
2. Something/_Description

Using `'%/[_]Description'`, "Description" is returned.

How can I restrict the result only to something like `"Something/_Description"`

Please note this is a standard SQL so supposed to be ran at both SQL Server/Oracle

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please specify more

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why SQL Server and Oracle both?

Comment: This is because `_` matches any (single) character, not the underscore

Comment: `%/[_]Description` does not match `Description`. What are you asking?

Comment: If you care about Oracle, then `%[_]Description` will return values that contain a `[` followed by one character followed by `]` followed by `Description` `[` and `]` ann have no special meaning for the `LIKE` operator in (standard) SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the [wildchar characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms179859.aspx) with the character defined in the [`ESCAPE` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms179859.aspx#code-snippet-8):

```
match_expression [ NOT ] LIKE pattern [ ESCAPE escape_character ]
```

In your case (untested):

```
WHERE ... LIKE '%/\_Description' ESCAPE '\'
```

This syntax is shared by SQL Server and [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm).

Comment: I suppose this is to escape '_'. Is it necessary with "ESCAPE '\' ? I have tried with this and both results returned.

Comment: @sophialiu - That's right. I don't have an Oracle or SQL Server box to test so I'm not sure about the *default* value. Setting yours should always work.

Comment: I've tried this in Oracle but got "Description" returned as well, don't know why.

Comment: @sophialiu [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad2687/1). Perhaps you should edit the the question and add some real code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to understand how the LIKE works:

```
// return rows like text111, text222, text333 etc
select * from users where username like 'text%';

// return rows like 111text, 222text, 333text etc
select * from users where username like '%text'; 

// return rows like 111text111, 222text222, 333text333 etc
select * from users where username like '%text%';
```

Comment: I am not sure how it is related to the question asked by OP!

Comment: I didn't fully understand what hist problem really is, so i tried to explain the 'like' logic, maybe it will help him

Comment: In that case you could have asked questions to OP via posting comments. I am saying so as your current answer is not answering the question and may lead you to some downvotes also.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the _ properly as it's a placeholder for like too. Based on your DBMS it should be ! so your statement could look like `%/!_Description`

Answer (score 0):

the `_` char is a special jolly character in Oracle. That's why the rows returned are not as you expected. If this query is generated by a program you can have a substitute the `_` with `[_]`.
Alternatively, you can use the `REPLACE` function in oracle:

```
REPLACE( string1, string_to_replace [, replacement_string] )
```

in your case

```
REPLACE( string_var, '_', [_] )
```

be aware that this may be a bottleneck if your function is called too many times, so I suggest to use an escape character.

example:

```
select REPLACE( 'aaaa_bbb', '_', '[_]' ) from dual
```